# Is there a way to compress an axis of an areachart in javafx?

Tags: javafx, charts

I am using a standard [JavaFX AreaChart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/AreaChart.html) to display certain values.

The NumberAxis provides methods for setting the [tickrate](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#tickUnitProperty) between these values, which only changes the distance between all ticks, but is not possible to make a variable tick rate using this.

Here is an edited picture of what I want to achieve:

[image]

As it is not possible to inherit from the final class [NumberAxis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html), I tried to copy-paste the entire code and just change the important parts. However, I don't understand what exactly needs to be changed.

I went through the [source code](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/11/source-code/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.java) but didn't understand how autoRange really works and how it could be changed to compress the axis.

Here is the example code for the uncompressed and (not yet) compressed diagram:

[image: diagram]

```
public class CompressedChartTest extends VBox {

    public CompressedChartTest() {
        AreaChart<Number, Number> chart1 = new AreaChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        chart1.setTitle("Uncompressed");

        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> dataSeries1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        dataSeries1.setName("Data series 1");
        dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2, 5));
        dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3, 2));
        dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(8, 10));
        dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(11, 3));
        dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(114, 4));
        dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(514, 2));

        chart1.getData().add(dataSeries1);

        this.getChildren().add(chart1);

        // --- //

        AreaChart<Number, Number> chart2 = new AreaChart<>(new CustomValueAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        chart2.setTitle("Compressed");

        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> dataSeries2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        dataSeries2.setName("Data series 2");
        dataSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2, 5));
        dataSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3, 2));
        dataSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(8, 10));
        dataSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(11, 3));
        dataSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(114, 4));
        dataSeries2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(514, 2));

        chart2.getData().add(dataSeries2);

        this.getChildren().add(chart2);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(new CompressedChartTest());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Basically copied and changed [source code of NumberAxis](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/11/source-code/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.java) to work inside my example application:

```
/**
 * An axis class that plots a range of numbers with major tick marks every tickUnit.
 * You can use any Number type with this axis.
 *
 * @since JavaFX 2.0
 */
public final class CustomValueAxis extends ValueAxis<Number> {

    private final StringProperty currentFormatterProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "currentFormatter", "");
    private final DefaultFormatter defaultFormatter = new DefaultFormatter(this);

    /**
     * The value between each major tick mark in data units. This is automatically set if we are auto-ranging.
     */
    private final DoubleProperty tickUnit = new SimpleDoubleProperty(5);

    public final double getTickUnit() {
        return tickUnit.get();
    }

    public final void setTickUnit(double value) {
        tickUnit.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty tickUnitProperty() {
        return tickUnit;
    }

    // -------------- CONSTRUCTORS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Creates an auto-ranging NumberAxis.
     */
    public CustomValueAxis() {
    }

    /**
     * Creates a non-auto-ranging NumberAxis with the given upper bound, lower bound and tick unit.
     *
     * @param lowerBound The lower bound for this axis, i.e. min plottable value
     * @param upperBound The upper bound for this axis, i.e. max plottable value
     * @param tickUnit   The tick unit, i.e. space between tickmarks
     */
    public CustomValueAxis(double lowerBound, double upperBound, double tickUnit) {
        super(lowerBound, upperBound);
        setTickUnit(tickUnit);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a non-auto-ranging NumberAxis with the given lower bound, upper bound and tick unit.
     *
     * @param axisLabel  The name to display for this axis
     * @param lowerBound The lower bound for this axis, i.e. min plottable value
     * @param upperBound The upper bound for this axis, i.e. max plottable value
     * @param tickUnit   The tick unit, i.e. space between tickmarks
     */
    public CustomValueAxis(String axisLabel, double lowerBound, double upperBound, double tickUnit) {
        super(lowerBound, upperBound);
        setTickUnit(tickUnit);
        setLabel(axisLabel);
    }

    // -------------- PROTECTED METHODS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Get the string label name for a tick mark with the given value.
     *
     * @param value The value to format into a tick label string
     * @return A formatted string for the given value
     */
    @Override
    protected String getTickMarkLabel(Number value) {
        StringConverter<Number> formatter = getTickLabelFormatter();
        if (formatter == null) formatter = defaultFormatter;
        return formatter.toString(value);
    }

    /**
     * Called to get the current axis range.
     *
     * @return A range object that can be passed to setRange() and calculateTickValues()
     */
    @Override
    protected Object getRange() {
        return new Object[]{
                getLowerBound(),
                getUpperBound(),
                getTickUnit(),
                getScale(),
                currentFormatterProperty.get()
        };
    }

    /**
     * Called to set the current axis range to the given range. If isAnimating() is true then this method should
     * animate the range to the new range.
     *
     * @param range   A range object returned from autoRange()
     * @param animate If true animate the change in range
     */
    @Override
    protected void setRange(Object range, boolean animate) {
        final Object[] rangeProps = (Object[]) range;
        final double lowerBound = (Double) rangeProps[0];
        final double upperBound = (Double) rangeProps[1];
        final double tickUnit = (Double) rangeProps[2];
        final double scale = (Double) rangeProps[3];
        final String formatter = (String) rangeProps[4];
        currentFormatterProperty.set(formatter);
        setLowerBound(lowerBound);
        setUpperBound(upperBound);
        setTickUnit(tickUnit);
        currentLowerBound.set(lowerBound);
        setScale(scale);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates a list of all the data values for each tick mark in range
     *
     * @param length The length of the axis in display units
     * @param range  A range object returned from autoRange()
     * @return A list of tick marks that fit along the axis if it was the given length
     */
    @Override
    protected List<Number> calculateTickValues(double length, Object range) {
        final Object[] rangeProps = (Object[]) range;
        final double lowerBound = (Double) rangeProps[0];
        final double upperBound = (Double) rangeProps[1];
        final double tickUnit = (Double) rangeProps[2];
        List<Number> tickValues = new ArrayList<>();
        if (lowerBound == upperBound) {
            tickValues.add(lowerBound);
        } else if (tickUnit <= 0) {
            tickValues.add(lowerBound);
            tickValues.add(upperBound);
        } else if (tickUnit > 0) {
            tickValues.add(lowerBound);
            if (((upperBound - lowerBound) / tickUnit) > 2000) {
                // This is a ridiculous amount of major tick marks, something has probably gone wrong
                System.err.println("Warning we tried to create more than 2000 major tick marks on a NumberAxis. " +
                        "Lower Bound=" + lowerBound + ", Upper Bound=" + upperBound + ", Tick Unit=" + tickUnit);
            } else {
                if (lowerBound + tickUnit < upperBound) {
                    // If tickUnit is integer, start with the nearest integer
                    double major = Math.rint(tickUnit) == tickUnit ? Math.ceil(lowerBound) : lowerBound + tickUnit;
                    int count = (int) Math.ceil((upperBound - major) / tickUnit);
                    for (int i = 0; major < upperBound && i < count; major += tickUnit, i++) {
                        if (!tickValues.contains(major)) {
                            tickValues.add(major);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            tickValues.add(upperBound);
        }
        return tickValues;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates a list of the data values for every minor tick mark
     *
     * @return List of data values where to draw minor tick marks
     */
    protected List<Number> calculateMinorTickMarks() {
        final List<Number> minorTickMarks = new ArrayList<>();
        final double lowerBound = getLowerBound();
        final double upperBound = getUpperBound();
        final double tickUnit = getTickUnit();
        final double minorUnit = tickUnit / Math.max(1, getMinorTickCount());
        if (tickUnit > 0) {
            if (((upperBound - lowerBound) / minorUnit) > 10000) {
                // This is a ridiculous amount of major tick marks, something has probably gone wrong
                System.err.println("Warning we tried to create more than 10000 minor tick marks on a NumberAxis. " +
                        "Lower Bound=" + getLowerBound() + ", Upper Bound=" + getUpperBound() + ", Tick Unit=" + tickUnit);
                return minorTickMarks;
            }
            final boolean tickUnitIsInteger = Math.rint(tickUnit) == tickUnit;
            if (tickUnitIsInteger) {
                double minor = Math.floor(lowerBound) + minorUnit;
                int count = (int) Math.ceil((Math.ceil(lowerBound) - minor) / minorUnit);
                for (int i = 0; minor < Math.ceil(lowerBound) && i < count; minor += minorUnit, i++) {
                    if (minor > lowerBound) {
                        minorTickMarks.add(minor);
                    }
                }
            }
            double major = tickUnitIsInteger ? Math.ceil(lowerBound) : lowerBound;
            int count = (int) Math.ceil((upperBound - major) / tickUnit);
            for (int i = 0; major < upperBound && i < count; major += tickUnit, i++) {
                final double next = Math.min(major + tickUnit, upperBound);
                double minor = major + minorUnit;
                int minorCount = (int) Math.ceil((next - minor) / minorUnit);
                for (int j = 0; minor < next && j < minorCount; minor += minorUnit, j++) {
                    minorTickMarks.add(minor);
                }
            }
        }
        return minorTickMarks;
    }

    /**
     * Measures the size of the label for a given tick mark value. This uses the font that is set for the tick marks.
     *
     * @param value tick mark value
     * @param range range to use during calculations
     * @return size of tick mark label for given value
     */
    @Override
    protected Dimension2D measureTickMarkSize(Number value, Object range) {
        final Object[] rangeProps = (Object[]) range;
        final String formatter = (String) rangeProps[4];
        return measureTickMarkSize(value, getTickLabelRotation(), formatter);
    }

    /**
     * Measures the size of the label for a given tick mark value. This uses the font that is set for the tick marks.
     *
     * @param value        tick mark value
     * @param rotation     The text rotation
     * @param numFormatter The number formatter
     * @return size of tick mark label for given value
     */
    private Dimension2D measureTickMarkSize(Number value, double rotation, String numFormatter) {
        String labelText;
        StringConverter<Number> formatter = getTickLabelFormatter();
        if (formatter == null) formatter = defaultFormatter;
        if (formatter instanceof DefaultFormatter) {
            labelText = ((DefaultFormatter) formatter).toString(value, numFormatter);
        } else {
            labelText = formatter.toString(value);
        }
        return measureTickMarkLabelSize(labelText, rotation);
    }

    /**
     * Called to set the upper and lower bound and anything else that needs to be auto-ranged.
     *
     * @param minValue  The min data value that needs to be plotted on this axis
     * @param maxValue  The max data value that needs to be plotted on this axis
     * @param length    The length of the axis in display coordinates
     * @param labelSize The approximate average size a label takes along the axis
     * @return The calculated range
     */
    @Override
    protected Object autoRange(double minValue, double maxValue, double length, double labelSize) {
        final Side side = getSide();
        // check if we need to force zero into range
        if (maxValue < 0) {
            maxValue = 0;
        } else if (minValue > 0) {
            minValue = 0;
        }
        // calculate the number of tick-marks we can fit in the given length
        int numOfTickMarks = (int) Math.floor(length / labelSize);
        // can never have less than 2 tick marks one for each end
        numOfTickMarks = Math.max(numOfTickMarks, 2);
        int minorTickCount = Math.max(getMinorTickCount(), 1);

        double range = maxValue - minValue;

        if (range != 0 && range / (numOfTickMarks * minorTickCount) <= Math.ulp(minValue)) {
            range = 0;
        }
        // pad min and max by 2%, checking if the range is zero
        final double paddedRange = (range == 0)
                ? minValue == 0 ? 2 : Math.abs(minValue) * 0.02
                : Math.abs(range) * 1.02;
        final double padding = (paddedRange - range) / 2;
        // if min and max are not zero then add padding to them
        double paddedMin = minValue - padding;
        double paddedMax = maxValue + padding;
        // check padding has not pushed min or max over zero line
        if ((paddedMin < 0 && minValue >= 0) || (paddedMin > 0 && minValue <= 0)) {
            // padding pushed min above or below zero so clamp to 0
            paddedMin = 0;
        }
        if ((paddedMax < 0 && maxValue >= 0) || (paddedMax > 0 && maxValue <= 0)) {
            // padding pushed min above or below zero so clamp to 0
            paddedMax = 0;
        }
        // calculate tick unit for the number of ticks can have in the given data range
        double tickUnit = paddedRange / (double) numOfTickMarks;
        // search for the best tick unit that fits
        double tickUnitRounded = 0;
        double minRounded = 0;
        double maxRounded = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double reqLength = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        String formatter = "0.00000000";
        // loop till we find a set of ticks that fit length and result in a total of less than 20 tick marks
        while (reqLength > length || count > 20) {
            int exp = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(tickUnit));
            final double mant = tickUnit / Math.pow(10, exp);
            double ratio = mant;
            if (mant > 5d) {
                exp++;
                ratio = 1;
            } else if (mant > 1d) {
                ratio = mant > 2.5 ? 5 : 2.5;
            }
            if (exp > 1) {
                formatter = "#,##0";
            } else if (exp == 1) {
                formatter = "0";
            } else {
                final boolean ratioHasFrac = Math.rint(ratio) != ratio;
                final StringBuilder formatterB = new StringBuilder("0");
                int n = ratioHasFrac ? Math.abs(exp) + 1 : Math.abs(exp);
                if (n > 0) formatterB.append(".");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                    formatterB.append("0");
                }
                formatter = formatterB.toString();

            }
            tickUnitRounded = ratio * Math.pow(10, exp);
            // move min and max to nearest tick mark
            minRounded = Math.floor(paddedMin / tickUnitRounded) * tickUnitRounded;
            maxRounded = Math.ceil(paddedMax / tickUnitRounded) * tickUnitRounded;
            // calculate the required length to display the chosen tick marks for real, this will handle if there are
            // huge numbers involved etc or special formatting of the tick mark label text
            double maxReqTickGap = 0;
            double last = 0;
            count = (int) Math.ceil((maxRounded - minRounded) / tickUnitRounded);
            double major = minRounded;
            for (int i = 0; major <= maxRounded && i < count; major += tickUnitRounded, i++) {
                Dimension2D markSize = measureTickMarkSize(major, getTickLabelRotation(), formatter);
                double size = side.isVertical() ? markSize.getHeight() : markSize.getWidth();
                if (i == 0) { // first
                    last = size / 2;
                } else {
                    maxReqTickGap = Math.max(maxReqTickGap, last + 6 + (size / 2));
                }
            }
            reqLength = (count - 1) * maxReqTickGap;
            tickUnit = tickUnitRounded;

            // fix for RT-35600 where a massive tick unit was being selected
            // unnecessarily. There is probably a better solution, but this works
            // well enough for now.
            if (numOfTickMarks == 2 && reqLength > length) {
                break;
            }
            if (reqLength > length || count > 20)
                tickUnit *= 2; // This is just for the while loop, if there are still too many ticks
        }
        // calculate new scale
        final double newScale = calculateNewScale(length, minRounded, maxRounded);
        // return new range
        return new Object[]{minRounded, maxRounded, tickUnitRounded, newScale, formatter};
    }

    // -------------- INNER CLASSES ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Default number formatter for NumberAxis, this stays in sync with auto-ranging and formats values appropriately.
     * You can wrap this formatter to add prefixes or suffixes;
     *
     * @since JavaFX 2.0
     */
    public static class DefaultFormatter extends StringConverter<Number> {
        private DecimalFormat formatter;
        private String prefix = null;
        private String suffix = null;

        /**
         * Construct a DefaultFormatter for the given NumberAxis
         *
         * @param axis The axis to format tick marks for
         */
        public DefaultFormatter(final CustomValueAxis axis) {
            formatter = axis.isAutoRanging() ? new DecimalFormat(axis.currentFormatterProperty.get()) : new DecimalFormat();
            final ChangeListener axisListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> formatter = axis.isAutoRanging() ? new DecimalFormat(axis.currentFormatterProperty.get()) : new DecimalFormat();
            axis.currentFormatterProperty.addListener(axisListener);
            axis.autoRangingProperty().addListener(axisListener);
        }

        /**
         * Construct a DefaultFormatter for the given NumberAxis with a prefix and/or suffix.
         *
         * @param axis   The axis to format tick marks for
         * @param prefix The prefix to append to the start of formatted number, can be null if not needed
         * @param suffix The suffix to append to the end of formatted number, can be null if not needed
         */
        public DefaultFormatter(CustomValueAxis axis, String prefix, String suffix) {
            this(axis);
            this.prefix = prefix;
            this.suffix = suffix;
        }

        /**
         * Converts the object provided into its string form.
         * Format of the returned string is defined by this converter.
         *
         * @return a string representation of the object passed in.
         * @see StringConverter#toString
         */
        @Override
        public String toString(Number object) {
            return toString(object, formatter);
        }

        private String toString(Number object, String numFormatter) {
            if (numFormatter == null || numFormatter.isEmpty()) {
                return toString(object, formatter);
            } else {
                return toString(object, new DecimalFormat(numFormatter));
            }
        }

        private String toString(Number object, DecimalFormat formatter) {
            if (prefix != null && suffix != null) {
                return prefix + formatter.format(object) + suffix;
            } else if (prefix != null) {
                return prefix + formatter.format(object);
            } else if (suffix != null) {
                return formatter.format(object) + suffix;
            } else {
                return formatter.format(object);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Converts the string provided into a Number defined by the this converter.
         * Format of the string and type of the resulting object is defined by this converter.
         *
         * @return a Number representation of the string passed in.
         * @see StringConverter#toString
         */
        @Override
        public Number fromString(String string) {
            try {
                int prefixLength = (prefix == null) ? 0 : prefix.length();
                int suffixLength = (suffix == null) ? 0 : suffix.length();
                return formatter.parse(string.substring(prefixLength, string.length() - suffixLength));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do this, please provide an [mcve].  There appears to be lots of methods for controlling values in the public API, e.g. [setting the tick unit](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#tickUnitProperty), and by subclassing, e.g. to override [calculateTickValues](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#calculateTickValues(double,java.lang.Object)).  I think you will need to improve the question to receive a useful answer.

Comment: "Implementing a completely custom number axis sadly requires using package private classes from javafx which are only accessible with workarounds." -> Why?  Do you have some examples?  What does "completely custom" mean?

Comment: @jewelsea I tried to overwrite calculateTickValues, but it's not not possible to extend the NumberAxis class because it's [final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#:~:text=public-,final,-class%20NumberAxis%0Aextends). I also tried copy pasting the entire number axis code but due to essential classes like 'com.sun.javafx.charts.ChartLayoutAnimator' being package private it is not trivial to do it like this.

Comment: Thanks, I understand a bit better now.  You still need to better explain what you want (in a further edit).  If it is non-trivial and you can't do it, and you really understand what you want to do, then it will be near impossible for somebody who can't understand well what you want to do.  The danger is that somebody could spend a lot of time coming up with what they think might be a solution only be to told, well, that is not what I really wanted.

Comment: I looked at the ChartLayoutAnimator code, it is straightforward and does not use any non-public API, you can just copy the code for it in addition to the NumberAxis code, then customize the NumberAxis or subclass it your heart's content.  Here is a [customization of a ValueAxis](http://blog.dooapp.com/2013/06/logarithmic-scale-strikes-back-in.html), in case you wanted to go another route.  The [mcve] may prove useful if you make one.

Comment: @jewelsea Okay, thanks for your input. I will add an example showing exactly what i want to achieve.

Comment: @jewelsea I updated my question and i would appreciate it if you could take another look at it, as i'm still trying to understand how the axis really works.

Comment: Do you need auto-ranging?  Is animation required?  Are your range and tick positions always constant?  Will the chart always be a constant size in pixels?  If the chart is resized, what will be the behavior?  Are the values always as you have in your example, e.g. major ticks in increments of 10 between 0 and 120 (rounded to 10s), and increments of 100 (rounded to 100s) for values after that with four minor ticks per major tick?  You can edit the question to add answers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a customized axis implementation (which is difficult), I advise placing the data in two separate charts, then merging the visuals of the two charts together.

[image: merge]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PartitionedChartApp extends Application {

    private static final double SMALL_TICK_UNIT = 10;
    private static final double LARGE_TICK_UNIT = 100;
    private static final double PARTITION_POINT = 100;

    // magic number for the amount to translate the large chart to merge seamlessly with the small chart.
    private static final double MERGE_TRANSLATE = -52;

    private static final String LARGE_DATA_CHART_CSS = """
            data:text/css,
            .axis:left {
                -fx-opacity: 0;
            }
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        AreaChart<Number, Number> smallDataChart = new AreaChart<>(
                new NumberAxis(0, PARTITION_POINT, SMALL_TICK_UNIT),
                new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1),
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Series<>(generateData())
                )
        );
        smallDataChart.setLegendVisible(false);
        smallDataChart.setAnimated(false);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        AreaChart<Number, Number> largeDataChart = new AreaChart<>(
                new NumberAxis(PARTITION_POINT, 600, LARGE_TICK_UNIT),
                new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1),
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Series<>(generateData())
                )
        );
        largeDataChart.setLegendVisible(false);
        largeDataChart.setAnimated(false);
        largeDataChart.getStylesheets().add(LARGE_DATA_CHART_CSS);
        largeDataChart.setTranslateX(MERGE_TRANSLATE);

        largeDataChart.prefWidthProperty().bind(
                smallDataChart.widthProperty().divide(2)
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(smallDataChart, largeDataChart)));
        stage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> generateData() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new XYChart.Data<>(2, 5),
                new XYChart.Data<>(3, 2),
                new XYChart.Data<>(8, 10),
                new XYChart.Data<>(11, 3),
                new XYChart.Data<>(114, 4),
                new XYChart.Data<>(514, 2)
        );
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```